# Exchange 2003 not receiving external emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2003

I am currently using Microsoft Exchange 2003 on a Windows Server 2003. I know! It's above my pay range to upgrade to 365.

Anyway, I have tested sending and receiving by sending to an eternal account. I usually add my internal as a carbon copy as the external account sends emails back to me. I have also had someone send me an attachment with the email with no success. I think it's also important to mention that there has been no bounce messages on either side of the email.

When I googled the issue, the only thing that comes back is a bunch of forums that make some suggestions that have not worked for me. I've tried to follow the suggestions to the best of my knowledge and I have had absolutely no success.

This is what I've done so far: a) Uninstall and reinstall outlook, b) tested port 25, and c) checked the recipient policy for discrepancies.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry about could not understand your issue very clearly. Do you mean that you cannot send or receives email from all external user? Can this issue be reproduced on your web mail?

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jeff. You're absolutely correct. I cannot send of receive external emails from certain people. Only my outgoing emails are getting recorded in exchange. I don't see incoming emails a all.